# Personnalized lists and calculate values

Tags: document-library

I've got a column in a List Library and I want that the user select in a Dropdown List a value and set a value in another column.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

For this there are three options

**Using Calculated Column**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

**Using Workflow**

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Workflow-actions-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010-A-quick-reference-guide-5a7ad276-0ed7-49b0-b652-e56a77dd96c6?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

**Using Event Receiver**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx